# How to get UUID of a bluetooth connected device in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I am making an app to collect some data and i am collecting some data using bluetooth sensor too, of which UUID is necessary as it tells the class of the device .
I have been able to get bluetooth state with use of flutter blue , but cant find a simple implementation to get the uuid of connected / paired devices

Comment: Which UUID are you talking about? Please give an example.

Comment: UUID of connected bluetooth devices